# How to add hyperlink to listbox item c#

Tags: c#, windows, runtime

I am doing a project where I add items in a `listview`, but items as websites, so is there a way that I could add a hyperlink in a `listViewItem` by my code?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: By "Windows Runtime" do you mean XAML-for-Windows-Store-apps?

Comment: Yes, but I need do this in xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with XAML-for-Windows-Store, but I understand it's very similar to WPF: just define an `<ItemTemplate>` for the listview:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Path=DisplayText}" NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Href}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This code assumes the items you're adding to the ListView have two string properties: `DisplayText` and `Href`.

Comment: This worked fine, but i want to know is there is a way to add a `hyperlink` in xaml.cs

Comment: @JoséAugustoAcorsi Current best-practices is to use the MVVM pattern and keep UI stuff in the XAML file and avoid "code-behind" logic in `.xaml.cs` files. Why are you wanting it in there?

Comment: I am developing a barcode scanner and when I sacan a barcode that contais a url i want tha it becomes a hyperlink, so the user could click the hyperlink and navigate to this url @Dai

Comment: @JoséAugustoAcorsi that has nothing to do with not having the template in XAML rather than your `.xaml.cs` file.